# Is there any concept like Register keys in android like .net

Tags: android

Is there any concept like Register keys in android like .net

Comment: What's a "Register key"? Are you referring to Windows registry keys (ew)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something called [SharedPrefrences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) which store key-value pairs.

Comment: if i store some key-value pairs of an application in sharedpreferences and uninstall application.can get the values.?